# Total MU Calculation when Outer CF is linked to Inner CF

Tags: ingress

[image]

What happens to the Y MU from the outer field when 2 fields are connected AFTER both fields are made. What would be the total MU gained in the checkpoint in the third step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The total MU gain would be X + Y + W + Z for the player and the team at the CP. But its contribution to the cycle calculation is not determined during the first 34 CPs. If these multiple fields are taken down during the cycle, they wouldn't count towards the cycle endpoint.