# Why is link not possible over short distance with no apparent link in the way?

Tags: ingress

Firstly, [here](https://www.ingress.com/intel?ll=34.952725,127.514933&z=14)'s the area I'm working in.
Here's a diagram created from the map:

[image: Portal field map]

For reference, these are the locations in the diagram: 
(apologies that it's not in English, that can't be helped)

- A: 강의기원
- B: Brilliant Metal
- C: 대석길 안전음식 먹거리
- 1: 연향상가 패션거리
- 2: 교감
- 3: 기록탑
- 4: 반석수
- 5: 창조
- 6: 책을 펴자

The outer triangle was an existing one that I didn't create. I took some time planning how to best build links within and eventually settled on the plan in the diagram. I was about 50% successful.  I was unable to make some links, but I don't really know why.

My plan was to travel down the numeric spine of the portals to collect keys, go to C first, connect each, then go to B and finish the connections, then travel back up the spine from 6 to 1 connecting each numeric portal. This is based on a similar process as described in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193681/total-mu-calculation-when-outer-cf-is-linked-to-inner-cf).

When I arrived at B, I was able to connect each portal until I got to 6, which refused to connect (This is the black line in the image). There is no apparent link in the way. I tried upgrading the resonators and adding a Link Amplifier, but neither worked.

I had a very similar problem when I arrived at B. This time I started connecting from the bottom going up. I was able to connect to 6 fine, but when I arrived at 1 (red line), it refused to connect with very similar issues. I tried the same things, but had no results.

Eventually I walked back up the numbered portals, tried to connect 6 to C from 6, but it still failed (though once the "Link Possible" voice clip played, no actual potential link appeared when I tried).  I traveled all the way up to 1, with no links possible between numbered portals (grey line), and was still unable to connect 1 to B.

In each case described, I had portal keys available. I don't see any links blocking the path, and distance shouldn't be an issue. I did notice that it was the last portal that I tried to connect (from B and C) that failed to connect.

What caused these links to not be possible?

Comment: You can always tap on a target portal and look at the error message that will tell you *why* you couldn't link to that particular portal.

Comment: I had seen the error message while attempting to link the numbered portals as "Portal within field" or something like this, but not realizing the difference between outgoing and incoming links, and having already linked to all the portals from the lettered portals, I error didn't seem to make sense. The answers below seem to clear it up though.

Comment: This is a very well-presented question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are some rules you have to consider when linking:

1. You can not link from a portal which is completely covered by fields, which applies to all portals 1 to 6.
2. Any portal can have unlimited incoming links, but only 8 outgoing links. It is hard to see but I'm pretty sure this limit had been reached when you tried to link from A, B and C.
   This link limit can be increased by deploying the new Softbank Ultra Link, which adds +8 outgoing links. All in all you can increase the limit to 40 outgoing links.

Comment: So ideally, if the outer field had not already existed, I could have gathered a pile of keys to A/B and worked from 6 up to A connecting each one to B/C and this would have eventually worked?

Comment: Exactly, that would have worked.

Comment: That's really great to know. I had no idea about this part. I'll have to plan more carefully in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see clearly all the links, but I suspect that each of the points had 8 originating links on it (i.e. links going elsewhere) and this is the reason.

There's a hard limit on the number of outgoing links as 8, and maximum total of 12.

Comment: There is no known limit on incoming links